# From conditional probability to "non" conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have a statement $B$ and an information I which is true for assumption (these are the terms used by my prof.). Now I consider two cases.

1. $B \neq I$; in this case I should consider $P(B | I)$
2. $B = I$; in this case is it correct to write $P(B)=P(I)=1$?

Comment: yes, it seems right to me, isn't this trivial?

Comment: Hi @Tortar it's the first time I study probability; thank you for your comment

Comment: hope you will find it interesting! I'm italia too anyway :), if you'd we can create a chat sometimes